# Bourne to grep and forward specific text from across a LAN

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking, sendmail

I'd like to develop a shell that keeps forwarding me the `grep`ed text(say compilation errors or warnings, in a single txt output) to some E-mail ID or on some NAS mount point, most importantly from across a LA Network(All running GNU/Linux with same bash version)

Is this possible without using `C`?

I'd thought of using `.bashrc` but that wouldn't help as it'd be invoked only once while logging-in.

What all things we'd need to consider here?

Any clues/hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `nc` command.  It is basically a `cat` that works across the network.  You can use it to create client/server scripts that do all kinds of things.